# How to change the headers for ACM paper?

Tags: header-footer

I am using the following `acmart.cls` file downladed here: [link](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/acmart.cls)

My main latex file's code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,bm}

\newcommand{\argmax}{\mathop{\hbox{argmax}}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\bm{x}}

% Copyright
\setcopyright{rightsretained}

% DOI
\acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN
\acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

% SELECT YOUR CONFERENCE/WORKSHOP BELOW...
\acmConference[WOODSTOCK'18]{ACM Woodstock conference}{July 29-August 3, 2018}{City, State, Country}
\acmYear{2018}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}

\begin{document}
\title[Paper Title Option]{Paper Title}

\author{Author1}\orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}
\affiliation{
    \institution{School of 1\\1 University}
    \streetaddress{Address1}
    \city{City1}
    \country{State, Country}
    \postcode{12345}
}
\email{abc@def.ghi}

\author{Author2}\orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}
\affiliation{
    \institution{School of 2\\2 University}
    \streetaddress{Address2}
    \city{City2}
    \country{State, Country}
    \postcode{12345}
}
\email{abc@def.ghi}

\begin{abstract}
blah-blah-blah.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Blah1; Blah2; Blah3; Blah4.}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
blah-blah-blah.
\newpage
\section{Related Work}
blah-blah-blah.
\newpage
\section{System Model}
blah-blah-blah.
\newpage
\section{Problem Formulation}
blah-blah-blah.
\newpage
\section{Proposed Algorithm}
blah-blah-blah.
\newpage
\section{Simulation Results}
blah-blah-blah.
\newpage
\section{Conclusion}
blah-blah-blah.

\begin{acks}
This research was supported by blah-blah-blah.
\end{acks}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography}

\end{document}
```

There is no header in the first page.

The headers in the even pages (i.e., 2, 4, 6, 8, ...) are as follows:

[image: 2]

The headers in the odd pages (i.e., 3, 5, 7, 9, ...) are as follows:

[image: 3]

I want to make all pages (including the first page) have the same header (left: Paper Title, right: Conference information as in the odd pages).

How can I change the header?

Actually, I want to know not only the way to force it to be solved, but also the way to solve my problem fundamentally by fixing the format file.

Answer (score 1):

Right after `\maketitle` you can simply insert `\thispagestyle{fancy}`.

If you want to change the `acmart` class, you can probably change [this line](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/blob/77e38a8816499037577cebd42486c6f6b801815a/acmart.dtx#L5133) to set the page style to `fancy` rather than `firstpage` (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

To the second part of the question, I would suggest you file `acmart.cls` and comment on the contents of the line `\acmconference` line. That should work for you :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do not change original class files, copy them, rename them, change them and use the new class file in your TeX code. Often you need not to change the original file, you can patch it ... You should add an compilable tex code with the solution to your answer to be valid ...

Comment: @Mensch Thank you for your comments.