# Problem in removing conference's information in ACM sigconf format

Tags: formatting, header-footer, acm

I have used the below [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346292/how-to-remove-conference-information-from-the-acm-2017-sigconf-template) to remove header and footer information but couldn't succeed in removing conference information("WOODSTOCK’18, July 29-August 3, 2018, City, State, Country") in the header (Figure is attached below). This question was originally asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442279/how-to-change-the-headers-for-acm-paper). Any leads or suggestion will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

```
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference information in first column
\pagestyle{plain} % removes running headers**strong text**
```

[image]

Comment: Currently I'm not allowed to comment yet, but did you find an answer for the above question? I'm having the same issue....

Comment: Try to modify  \acmConference[]{}{}{} in the ACM class. usually, it is not advisable to make changes in the class.